# How to play cube-mapped video using gearvr sample application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I have 360 video stream which is in cube format, where complete 360 image is captured as projection on 6 faces of a cube and each video frame has all 6 faces as shown in the image.
[image: Cube-mapped 360 video frmae]

I want to play this video using [gvr360video](https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos/tree/master/gvr-360video) sample application.

At high level, this sample application works as below.

1) Create a media player.

2) Create a GVRSphereSceneObject.

3) Get the GVRMesh object of this SphereSceneObject.

4) Create a GVRVideoSceneObject and ask it to use the media player and GVRMesh object.

5) Play a video which has equi-rectangular 360 video.

To play cube mapped video, I changed some code to use GVRCubeSceneObject instead of GVRSphereSceneObject. But I know this is not sufficient. Since all faces of cube is part of the frame, I should be able to specify which part of the frame should be projected to which face of the cube.

I read the API details of [GVRCubeSceneObject](http://docs.gearvrf.org/org/gearvrf/scene_objects/GVRCubeSceneObject.html), [GVRVideoSceneObject](http://docs.gearvrf.org/org/gearvrf/scene_objects/GVRVideoSceneObject.html), [GVRMesh](http://docs.gearvrf.org/org/gearvrf/GVRMesh.html) and some other objects. But I am not able to find the required API.

Could somebody help me in this.